# Flutter/Dart: Parse the results of Ping Function

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, networking, ping

So I am using this function that utilizes the dart_ping.dart package
and I would like to only extract the ip, ttl and time from the result this function is giving.

```
  void ping(String site) async {
// Create ping object with desired args
final ping = Ping(site, count: 5);

print('Running command: ${ping.command}');
// Begin ping process and listen for output
ping.stream.listen((PingData event) {
  setState(() {
    ping1 = event;
  });
  pingsArray.add(event);

  print(event.summary);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you have to extract them from the `PingData` so in below code I will show you how to get the values. the `ip`, `ttl`, `time` from the response are assigned to the varialbles `ip`, `ttl`, `time`. You can probably start from there. Since I do not exactly know what you want to achieve, this is probably all I can show you.

```
void _ping(String site) async {
   // Create ping object with desired args
   final ping = Ping(site, count: 5);

   print('Running command: ${ping.command}');
   // Begin ping process and listen for output
   ping.stream.listen((PingData event) {
      final res = event.response;
      if (res == null) return;
      final ip = res.ip;
      final ttl = res.ttl;
      final time = res.time;
    });
}
```

Thank you.